# Movie about a toy factory and war toys?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie about a toy factory. From what I remember, it was about competing sides making toys - one side made violent war toys and the others made nice friendly ones. The makers of the war toys had some evil intention behind them.

Other details:

- Live action & color
- Probably 10-25 years old
- Saw it on TV
- There was a golf cart driving around the factory
- The war toys shot exploding missiles and bullets
- There was a giant bouncing ball

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the movie you are looking for is [Toys (1992)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105629/) starring Robin Williams

> When a military general inherits a **toy making company and begins making war toys**, his employees band together to stop him before he ruins the name of Zevo Toys forever.

The below image is a golf cart driving around the factory.

[image: Golfcart]

Comment: It's definitely Toys. In the final confrontation there's a large bouncing ball that pursues them down the hallways of the factory.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds a bit like [Small Soldiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Soldiers). There it was a toy factory mistakenly (or intentionally?) building hitec military chips into their toys (action figures) and these then get into the environment of a normal US town. There are two parties: a group of soldiers (evil) and a group of peaceful fantasy creatures (good) and they fight against each other with the humans getting into crossfire.

Comment: One of the partners bought ex-military chips as they were cheaper than the regular chips.

Comment: @AidanO Admittedly I haven't seen the movie in years, but I remember him getting the military chips (not ex-military) because he was concerned that the toys wouldn't be considered engaging enough. The setup to the whole idea was that they were manufacturing educational toys, which the execs didn't like because they didn't sell, so they built toy soldiers instead. One of the two developers approached the change in concept a little too overzealously and ordered the military "learning" chips, which later led to the "...OH!" scene between them.

Comment: @polynomial, as I recall the chips had been rejected by the military, not a big plot point though.